# required directive return false, when field is empty. but when i console the form object it shows required is true why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[created plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fY5o5ul97XUn6uzVAu1J?p=preview)
i have following html code :

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mk" required/>
    <input type="submit" placeholder="submit" ng-click="submitIt(form1)" >
</form>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.submitIt=function(form1){
    console.log(form1);
}
```

when i submit form without any value(empty field),and see in console.it shows `required:true`.
but according to required directive it return `required : false`

required directive provided by angular.js library:

```
var requiredDirective = function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl) return;
      attr.required = true; // force truthy in case we are on non input element

      var validator = function(value) {
        if (attr.required && ctrl.$isEmpty(value)) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('required', false);
          return;
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('required', true);
          return value;
        }
      };

      ctrl.$formatters.push(validator);
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);

      attr.$observe('required', function() {
        validator(ctrl.$viewValue);
      });
    }
  };
};
```

i am confused,why it is like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the required is true, and there is no input then the validity is false.

the false you see in directive is for validity

```
   ctrl.$setValidity('required', false);
```

it is setting validity as false, which means if the input is required and no input has been provided, then the field is in invalid state...

Comment: but in console if you see $error object,it will show required:true.
is this require:true. what require:true indicate in $error object ?

Comment: in console i see $error.required as array, where do you see false?

Comment: please see this :  form1.$error.required[0].$error.required . i also updated plunker.

Comment: i printed the value on screen, it is showing as 'error : true' and not false. check plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DV0CHVrz6VgArntSS6R8?p=preview

Comment: yes it is showing 'error : true', but required directive is returning false,when no input is provided.

Comment: fyi, its not returning false, it is setting validity to false... its a negation. e.g. do you require this field, if you say yes, and then if its not provided, so the field is not inline with your expected, so its not valid, so set it to false

Comment: @harishr: This will set the validity to false, but while iterating through the error object even if the field has viewvalue it pops up in the $error.required array which is troubling during validation.Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-disabled` on bitton to prevent submit form.

```
    <input type="submit" placeholder="submit" ng-click="submitIt(form1)" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid || !form1.$dirty">
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MagPxS2JJftWbJzOycs2?p=preview)